# Item doesn't store in ArrayList with different XML structure

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist, rss

Currently I'm doing some exercise on processing XML and storing into ArrayList, it work well when I'm using [this](http://malaysiakini.com/en/news.rss) xml. But when I switch to [this](http://www.thestar.com.my/rss/editors-choice/main/) xml, suddenly the data is not stored in ArrayList. I have done some output testing and it seems the data did not pass here to `feedItems.add(new FeedItem(title,date));`. I hope someone can explain to me what is going on with my code and how I can fix this issue.

MainActivity.java

```
new ReadRSS(MainActivity.this, listView, "http://www.thestar.com.my/rss/editors-choice/main/").execute();
```

ReadRSS.java

```
   public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text;
    String title = null;
    String date = null;

    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();

        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = myParser.getName();

            switch (event){

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        int eventChild = myParser.next();
                        //int innerLoop = 1;


                        String tagNameChild = "";
                            while(eventChild != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

                                if(eventChild == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                                    tagNameChild = myParser.getName();
                                    // Output Test
                                    //Log.d("Tag ", tagNameChild);
                                }

                                else if (eventChild == XmlPullParser.TEXT){

                                    text = myParser.getText();
                                    // Output Test
                                    //Log.d("Test ", text);


                                    if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){

                                        title = text;
                                        // Output Test
                                        //Log.d("Title ", myParser.getText());
                                    }
                                    else if(tagNameChild.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){

                                        date = text;
                                        // Output Test
                                        //Log.d("PubDate ", myParser.getText());

                                    }
                                }

                                else if (eventChild == XmlPullParser.END_TAG){


                                    if(myParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){

                                        feedItems.add(new FeedItem(title,date));
                                        // Output Test
                                        //Log.d("Test ", title);

                                    }

                                }

                                eventChild = myParser.next();

                            //innerLoop++;
                            }

                        //Output Test
                        for(int i = 0; i < feedItems.size(); i++) {
                            Log.d("Title", feedItems.get(i).getTitle());
                            Log.d("Date", feedItems.get(i).getPubDate());
                        }
                    }

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    break;

            }


            event = myParser.next();

        }


        parsingComplete = false;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

FeedItem.java

```
 public class FeedItem {

String title;
String link;
String description;
String pubDate;
String thumbnailUrl;


public FeedItem (String title, String pubDate){

    this.title = title;
    this.pubDate = pubDate;

}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}



public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you did wrong, because I copied your parser code and FeedItem and successfully parsed both xmls!

1. XML - 50 FeedItems
2. XML - 10 FeedItems

However the parsing was not fully OK, because your titles and dates were overwritten with empty text, so I `cleared` after every EndTag the `tagNameChild`variable. After that I got all the FeedItems with the correct title and date!

Code fix:

```
else if (eventChild == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {


    if (myParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

        feedItems.add(new FeedItem(title, date));
        // Output Test
        //Log.d("Test ", title);

    }
    tagNameChild = "";

}
```